# Let all zeros of $f(z)=a_0 z^n + ... + a_n$ be inside c. Find $\int_{c} \frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let all zeros of $f(z)=a_0 z^n + ... + a_n$ be inside c. Find
$\int_{c} \frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)}$

I dont know how to approach this problem

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/599109/42969

Comment: Observe the integrand function ressembles the Argument Principle (generalization of)...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Observe that $f(z)$ is a polynomial and can be expressed as
$$f(z)=a_0(z-z_1)...(z-z_n)$$
where $z_k,k=1..n$ are zeros. Then, it is not difficult to see (left as an exercise) that
$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{1}{z-z_1}+\frac{1}{z-z_2}+...+\frac{1}{z-z_n}$$
Now, taking the integral [should be really easy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula). And don't forget about [Vieta's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)!